# Need help using predicates to filter NSArray that presents data in UITableVIew

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have NSArray that gets its data from a mySQL database.

I need to filter this data based on a hard-coded string `"Customer1"`

**The following is what I have so far:**

```
import UIKit

class showCustomerDetails: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FeedDetailProtocol  {



    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedStock : DetailModel = DetailModel()


    @IBOutlet weak var stockResultsFeed: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.stockResultsFeed.delegate = self
        self.stockResultsFeed.dataSource = self

        let detailModel = FeedDetail()
        detailModel.delegate = self
        detailModel.downloadItems()

    }
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray) {

        feedItems = items
        self.stockResultsFeed.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of feed items
        return feedItems.count

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Retrieve cell
        let cellIdentifier: String = "customerDetails"
        let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
        myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        // Get the stock to be shown
        let item: DetailModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! DetailModel



        // Configure our cell title made up of name and price
        let customerDetails = [item.code, item.manufacturer, item.model].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: " — ")



        print(customerDetails)
        // Get references to labels of cell
        myCell.textLabel!.text = customerDetails

        return myCell
    }


}
```

**The following is what I was thinking of doing, but I am not sure how to properly apply it:**

```
let searchString = "Customer1"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@", searchString)
let searchDataSource = feedItems.filter { predicate.evaluateWithObject($0) }
```

**And then:**

```
let item: DetailModel = searchDataSource[indexPath.row] as! DetailModel
```

**NSArray data is coming from:**

```
import Foundation

protocol FeedDetailProtocol: class {
    func itemsDownloaded(items: NSArray)
}


class FeedDetail: NSObject, URLSessionDataDelegate {



    weak var delegate: FeedDetailProtocol!

    let urlPath = "https://www.example.com/test1/test1.php"

    func downloadItems() {

        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)

        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }else {
                print("details downloaded")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }

    func parseJSON(_ data:Data) {

        var jsonResult = NSArray()

        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)

        }

        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let stocks = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count
        {

            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

            let stock = DetailModel()

            //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
            if let code = jsonElement[“code”] as? String,
                let customer = jsonElement["customer"] as? String,
                let manufacturer = jsonElement["manufacturer"] as? String,
                let model = jsonElement["model"] as? String

            {
                print(code)
                print(manufacturer)
                print(model)
                print(customer)
                stock.code = code
                stock.manufacturer = manufacturer
                stock.model = model
                stock.customer = customer

            }

            stocks.add(stock)

        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in

            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(items: stocks)

        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Swift, you should not be using NSArray or filtering with NSPredicate.

Comment: And if you are using MySQL, you should probably be filtering at the level of SELECT so you receive exactly the filtered data you want in the first place.

Comment: @matt I am fairly new to Swift, what is the appropriate way of doing this?

Comment: I cannot do it at a mySQL level as the query used is being used for other things as well

Comment: Okay fair enough. Anyway use [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), not NSArray, and just call Array's [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method.

Comment: The data is presenting correctly right now in Swift using NSArray. It is just not filtered. I think it would be better to use NSArray, I'm just not sure how to filter it.

Comment: "I think it would be better to use NSArray" And I'm suggesting that it wouldn't. Use Array and then it will be easy (if you give sufficient info about what's in the array) to tell you how to filter it.

Comment: I posted an update showing where the values for the array are coming from

Comment: Also for your JSON you should using Codable, not JSONSerialization. Basically you are trying write your code in Objective-C even though you are actually using Swift. That is counterproductive.

Comment: I appreciate your help, most of my application is written this way, so it would be difficult to go and change it now, I will do so in the future

Answer (score 0):

This is Swift. Use [Array](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array), not NSArray, and just call Array's [`filter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) method. NSArray belongs to Cocoa and Objective-C; you should use native Swift types and Swift methods as much as possible.

If you insist on filtering an NSArray using a Cocoa Objective-C method, and you insist on using NSPredicate, the simplest approach is to form your predicate with [`init(block:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate/1416182-init).

Here's a simple illustration:

```
    let arr = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"] as NSArray
    let p = NSPredicate { element, _ in
        return (element as? String)?.contains("a") ?? false
    }
    let arr2 = arr.filtered(using: p)
    print(arr2) // [Manny, Jack]
```

But (just to drive home the point) it's so much simpler in native Swift:

```
    let arr = ["Manny", "Moe", "Jack"]
    let arr2 = arr.filter {$0.contains("a")}
```

Comment: Can you please show me an example of how this could be done?

Comment: Did so, but I don't approve.